# asking red turtles to avoid other turtles and move to one of its neighbor which is empty and has highest conc

Tags: netlogo

I'm new to Netlogo. Here I'm trying ask red turtles to move towards the hight conc. patches. yellow turtles do not move. I did that! but I also want to ask the red turtles to avoid the patches which have yellow or red turtles on them and move to the neighbor of high conc.. In my code I asked them to stop once they become next to an occupied patch just because I couldn't do it. I also want to avoid getting 2 turtles on the same patch at any time. Any one could help me with that please?

```
    patches-own [conc] 

to set-up
clear-all
ask patch random-pxcor random-pycor [
set conc 200
set pcolor scale-color red conc 0 1]
crt 5 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor  set shape "circle" set color red]
crt 20 [setxy random-xcor random-ycor set shape "circle" set color yellow]
reset-ticks
end




to go
diffuse conc 0.1
ask patches [set pcolor scale-color red conc 0 1]
ask turtles with [color = red]
[ifelse  not any? turtles-on neighbors
[if [conc] of max-one-of neighbors [conc]  > conc [
face max-one-of neighbors4 [conc]
 move-to max-one-of neighbors4 [conc]]]

[stop]

]

tick

end
```

Comment: sorry @Fiver I didn't get your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your code would read a little nicer if you used `let` to avoid repetition, like this:

```
let target max-one-of neighbors [conc]
if [conc] of target > conc [
  face target
  move-to target
]
```

For some different possible approaches to enforcing a "one turtle per patch" rule, see the One Turtle Per Patch Example model, in the Code Examples section of NetLogo's Models Library.

I assume that `ifelse not any? turtles-on neighbors` is your attempt to make turtles avoid occupied patches. But as you've written it, it has a stronger effect than that — it makes it so that any turtle with an adjacent occupied patch won't move at all.

I think you may have meant something more like:

```
ask turtles with [color = red] [
  let targets neighbors with [not any? turtles-here]
  let target max-one-of targets [conc]
  if target != nobody and [conc] of target > conc [
    face target
    move-to target
  ]
]
```

Hope this helps.